# - ERROR | [OSX] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unsupported file type: ) during validation

Tags: ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

Hey guys I am using cocoapods in my kotlin multiplatform project. I am trying to do private pod spec from the [doc](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html). When I am trying to push the code I am getting weried issue on my terminal

```
Validating spec
 -> VivekMyCocoaPod (0.0.1)
    - WARN  | license: Invalid license type.
    - NOTE  | url: The URL (https://github.com/vivek-modi/KotlinPod.git) is not reachable.
    - WARN  | http: The URL (``) doesn't use the encrypted HTTPS protocol. It is crucial for Pods to be transferred over a secure protocol to protect your users from man-in-the-middle attacks. This will be an error in future releases. Please update the URL to use https.
    - ERROR | [OSX] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unsupported file type: ) during validation.
```

**.podspec**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name                     = 'VivekMyCocoaPod'
    spec.version                  = '0.0.1'
    spec.homepage                 = 'https://github.com/vivek-modi/KotlinPod.git'
    spec.source                   = { :http=> ''}
    spec.authors                  = ''
    spec.license                  = ''
    spec.summary                  = 'Some description for a Kotlin/Native module'
    spec.vendored_frameworks      = 'build/cocoapods/framework/MyFramework.framework'
    spec.libraries                = 'c++'
                
                
                
    spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH' => ':',
        'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME' => 'MyFramework',
    }
                
    spec.script_phases = [
        {
            :name => 'Build VivekMyCocoaPod',
            :execution_position => :before_compile,
            :shell_path => '/bin/sh',
            :script => <<-SCRIPT
                if [ "YES" = "$COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD" ]; then
                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD environment variable set to \"YES\""
                  exit 0
                fi
                set -ev
                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                "$REPO_ROOT/../../../../private/var/folders/bh/nx_31y193190m5vz8sd9y6jm0000gq/T/wrap1922loc/gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
            SCRIPT
        }
    ]
                
end
```

Comment: this is critical message: `The URL (https://github.com/vivek-modi/KotlinPod.git) is not reachable.`. Probably your repo is private, [check out](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) how to use cocoapods with a private repo

Comment: @PylypDukhov I am already reading the same doc. That's why I don't understand what should I do?

Comment: do you really have write access to the repo, as doc suggests? try do `git push` in command line from the repo folder, you may be using some GUI app but don't have credentials in the command line